# Python Object Reference

Tags: python

I am a bit confused on how object values persist in python.

Let say I have an class object `a` that has a specific set of attributes attached to it. Multiple classes `B`, `C` have their own references to class `a` when each of them are created. Only class `C` can modify stuff in class `a`. When it is modified, does class `B` pick them up? From creating my own example they seem to do so.

My question is are there any instances where I should be aware of when changes to wont be picked up? When does python create an copy of class `a`? More specifically, what will create a copy of it that wont affect the original `a`.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def changeX(self,num):
        self.x = num


class B:

    def __init__(self,classA):
        self.x = classA

class C:
    def __init__(self,classA):
        self.x = classA

    def ChangeA(self,num):
        self.x.changeX(num)

c_a = A()
c_b = B(c_a)
c_c = C(c_a)


c_c.ChangeA(2)

# All returns 2
c_a.x
c_b.x.x
c_c.x.x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment statements in Python don't copy objects, they create bindings between the target and an object.

An easy to understand guide on how this different from other languages is available [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/thematic_tutorials/tutorial-objects-and-classes.html).

When you need to change an assigned object so it does not affect other assigned objects you can use the `copy` module. (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html)

```
import copy

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def changeX(self,num):
        self.x = num


class B:

    def __init__(self,classA):
        self.x = classA

class C:
    def __init__(self,classA):
        self.x = classA

    def ChangeA(self,num):
        self.x.changeX(num)

c_a = A()
c_b = B(c_a)
c_c = copy.deepcopy(C(c_a))


c_c.ChangeA(2)

c_a.x #1
c_b.x.x #1
c_c.x.x #2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create a copy Python won't create a copy for you. You can use the `copy` module to create copies of objects or you can create a new object with the same values.

In your example there is only once instance of class `A` and each of the `c_a`, `c_b` and `c_c` have access to it. That's why you're seeing `2` in each case as they're all the same attribute on the same object.